# Odd behavior with tag suggestion function

Tags: discussion

I wanted to select 'Entity Framework' for a tag for a new question. I start typing 'ent' and I see 'Entity Framework' among the listed tags. Then if I add the 'i', 'Entity-Framework-4' shows up which is a more precise tag.

My question is why didn't it show up for 'ent'? specially when some of the tags shown weren't prefixed with 'ent' as if there were no more tags starting with 'ent'?  I would have never known 'Entity-Framework-4' existed had I not typed 'i' and my inclination would to select 'Entity-Framework' before adding another character.

Answer (score 2):

It is top n matches by frequency (# of questions with that particular tag), so for that string, it probably wasn't in the top n.

Comment: In some way it doesn't make sense to me that words that contain 'ent' in the middle or end with 'ent' have higher priority than words that start with 'ent', regardless of the frequency. The frequency is for # used. Not because it contains a particular keyword somewhere INSIDE the tag.